# Help me get two branched third party dlls with the same name to play nice

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, dll

At one point foo.dll was one file - but the owning party split into two companies. Both of the new companies have their own version of foo.dll. The namespaces and class names are the same - but the business logic is different.

My task is this - make a project that nests a UI control form company A's foo.dll with another UI control that exists company B's foo.dll.

Since the assembly name, namespaces, and class names are exactly the same visual studio thinks that the only difference between the two foo.dll files is in the versioning. As a result it will not let me add both DLLs to the project.

In other words.... A.B.C and A.B.D both exist in company a's foo.dll and company b's foo.dll.

I am required to nest A.B.D from company B's foo.dll into A.B.C of company A's dll.

What is the best way to do this? Please note that the object A.B.C has references to its own company's A.B.D object and vice versa in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx

[two different DLL with same namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672920/two-different-dll-with-same-namespace)

give it a try anyway.

Comment: Using an alias can solve the problem of adding two references with the same class names, but it will not allow you to mix the classes from either reference. `ref1::A.B.C` is never a `ref2::A.B.C`. There's no solution to this really, they can't be mixed.