# How to differentiate between two assemblies in a Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an extension method:

```
.ToDescription()
```

This method exists in a `MyExtensions` class in the `My.Methods` namespace, in an assembly named `MyAssembly1`. I also have other extension methods in a `MyExtensions` class in the `My.Methods` namespace, but in a different assembly named `MyAssembly2`.

Both of these assemblies are referenced in my project. `MyAssembly2.My.Methods.MyExtensions` contains no `.ToDescription()` method.

I wish to use the `.ToDescription()` extension method in a Razor view, but I'm getting an ambiguous reference error:

> The type 'MyExtensions' exists in both 'MyAssembly1' and 'MyAssembly2'

Is there a way to tell a Razor view which assembly to use, when both the namespaces and the classes are the same?

Note: I did attempt some research on this, but due to the complex nature of the question, no usable results were returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue,it's ok in .net 8(what's your .net version?),you could try update the .net version.

A workaround for you to fix Error CS0433 in Razor View:

In project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj" >
      <Aliases>CustomTypes</Aliases>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

In program.cs:

```
extern alias CustomTypes;
global using _MyExtension = CustomTypes::My.Methods;
```

In your razor view:

```
@using _MyExtension
```

Here's the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0433) related Error CS0433,hopes help

Comment: .NET 8 as well. But I don't think it's going to be possible, at least not in my case. VB.NET doesn't support [`extern alias`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6540971/722393). Nevertheless, I marked yours as the answer because I didn't specify VB.NET at the beginning. The good news is that it works with package references as well as project references.