# Possible to reference two different assemblies with the same name in a project? different binaries

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, .net-assembly

this is a strange one...maybe.

Summary:  I'm using the 32feet libraries for bluetooth communication.  We have shared code which runs on both .Net compact (for mobile) and standards. Net.

I'm searching for a suggestive solution or some design pattern that may exist that I'm not aware of.

32feet provides one assembly for compact framework and one for standard.  Assemblies have the same name,  same class names.

I need to come up with a solution where I have a generic class which anyone can consume that will know how is connecting.  I am not even sure if this is possible.  The solution im leaning towards so far is having two separate assemblies... One for mobile. .. One for standard.  It doesn't feel right and I'm wondering if there's a better route to go.  Is it possible to use so sort of DI to choose the correct binary at runtime?

Example:

```
Public abstract BluetoothBase
{
     Public BluetoothBase ()
     {
     }

     Public int Connect ()
     {
          // this is where problem lies.  Need to tell class which assembly to use based on OS.  So far I'm finding this is not possible. ..
     }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try to add both in VS to your project?  Do you get any errors, and if so what do those say?  Also, how about loading assemblies dynamically at run-time, where you'd only load one depending on OS and then call into those?

Comment: Lb22 thanks for your reply.  I can, for example, add both if I rename one.  The problem becomes that both assemblies have the same class names within.  For example var btc = new BluetoothClient() is the same call for both assemblies.  Ideally...I would like to do exactly what your said... reference each assembly separately based on the os.  It's just the fact that both assemblies seem to contain the same namespaces, same class names,  same constructor signatures,  etc...

Comment: Would extern alias solve this problem?   Looks like it might.   I will update this thread if it does

Comment: For anyone else looking for extern alias, see [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173212%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (note also the community comment at the bottom).

Comment: Related post - [two different DLL with same namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3672920/465053)

Answer (score 1):

This would be adding an interface and 2 implementations that need to be maintained but this I think would accomplish what you are going for.

Define a interface in the shared code.

```
public interface IBluetooth
{
    //methods you need from the base class.
}
```

In the mobile platform specific code

```
public class MobileBluetooth : IBluetooth
{
//Implement
}
```

In the desktop platform specific code

```
public class DesktopBlueooth : IBluetooth
{
    //Implement
}
```

And for your framework or bluetooth base class have an initialize method where you inject in your interface.

```
public abstract BluetoothBase
{
    private IBluetooth _connection;

    public Init(IBluetooth connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
    }

    public int Connect()
    {
         //use the interface to connect.
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this!   Simple and straightforward.   I will try this tomorrow when I get to work and accept I'd it fits the bill.   Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

In short,  the easiest way to do this is the following:

You have two assemblies with the exact same name, same class types, same everything.  Only difference?   I my case one was compiled for desktop while the other was compiled for compact framework

I this case the assemblies are called InTheHand.Personal.Net

The easiest approach is to do the following:

1. Copy each respective assembly to its own folder.
2. In visual studio,  right click on your project and select "unload project".  This is necessary because the reference manager will not allow you to add two assemblies with the same name.   To get around this you manually edit the project file.
3. Add two reference elements to three reference section.   Each one pointing to the path location of the dll.
4. Give each. Dll is own alias.

The in you're code, just use the extern alias directive to reference each assembly.

If you're doing mobile versus nonmobile like me,  wrap each one in a #if PocketPC directive

Then create a using alias to each