# Windsor Ioc Auto Register Classes namespace collision for duplicate type across assemblies

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I would like suggestions on if this usage is possible with Windsor and how to achieve. The details (simplified to illustrate the issue) are as follows.

```
AssemblyA namespace com.foo
   IRepository<T>

AssemblyB namespace com.foo  
   Repository<Data> extends IRepository<Data>
   Service -> Resolves Repository<Data> via Windsor

AssemblyC namespace com.foo
   Repository<Data> extends IRepository<Data>
   Service -> Resolves Repository<Data> via Windsor

AssemblyB references AssemblyA
AssemblyC references AssemblyA
```

Services are deployed in WCF as follows:

```
<add relativeAddress="v1/Service.svc"  service="com.foo.Service, AssemblyB" />
<add relativeAddress="v2/Service.svc"  service="com.foo.Service, AssemblyC" />
```

Registered via Windsor as follows:

```
var allTypesFromBinDir =
          Classes.FromAssemblyInDirectory(
              new AssemblyFilter(path));

Container.Register(allTypesFromBinDir.BasedOn(typeof(IRepository<>))
                                     .WithService.Base()
                                     .LifestyleTransient());
```

What I want is to scope registration to include the Assembly in qualifying Data for registering and resolving.  What occurs is the first assembly scanned AssemblyB registers IRepository with assemblyB.Data and does not register AssemblyC IRespository with assemblyC.Data.

The following occurs or vice versa depending on order dll's scanned.

AssemblyB resolves correctly.
AssemblyC fails to resolve with  "No component for supporting the service"

```
Container.Resolve(IRepository<Data>)
```

So it seems that the registration treats the two namespaces as the same from registration purpose but resolving takes assembly into account?  I expect Registration to take assembly qualification into account as well.

In otherwords...
Windsor "should"  I think:

```
Register AssemblyA.IRepository<AssemblyB.Data> with AssemblyB.Repository<AssemblyB.Data>
And
Register AssemblyA.IRepository<AssemblyC.Data> with AssemblyC.Repository<AssemblyC.Data>
```

Then Windsor "should" I think:

```
AssemblyB Service resolves AssemblyA.IRepository<AssemblyB.Data> to AssemblyB.Repository<AssemblyB.Data>
And
AssemblyC Service resolves AssemblyA.IRepository<AssemblyC.Data> to AssemblyC.Repository<AssemblyC.Data>
```

Instead
Windsor is:

```
Register AssemblyA.IRepository<AssemblyB.Data> with AssemblyB.Repository<AssemblyB.Data>
And
Does not Register AssemblyA.IRepository<AssemblyC.Data> with AssemblyC.Repository<AssemblyC.Data>    I believe it matches AssemblyA.IRepository<Data> from prior registration ignoring Assembly.
```

Then Windsor is:

```
AssemblyB Service resolves AssemblyA.IRepository<AssemblyB.Data> to AssemblyB.Repository<AssemblyB.Data>
And
AssemblyC Service does not resolve AssemblyA.IRepository<AssemblyC.Data> but throws component not found.  If AssemblyC is scanned first then the exception happens in AssemblyB Service.
```

I have looked at posts demonstrating something close to what I want by Krzysztof [here](http://kozmic.net/tag/castle/) using IGenericServiceStrategy

However,  this strategy seems to work only with Component registration using implemented by.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So to rephrase, you want `AssemblyB.Service` to resolve `AssemblyB.Repository`, and `AssemblyC.Service` to resolve `AssemblyC.Repository`?  But the service in C is getting an exception while the on in B works as you'd like?

Comment: Essentially;)  Your first question resolving AssemblyB to AssemblyB.Respository etc..  is absolutely correct.  The second part of question is correct but..  to be clear the exception happens depending on which assembly is registered first.  I can have the reverse situation if I force AssemblyC to be installed first the AssemblyB will get resolution exception.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same namespaces and types in different assemblies is not a good choice. It requires additional job anyway to resolve them withing your clients - [`extern alias <name>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3672987/902734).

```
extern alias v2Alias;
extern alias v1Alias;
```

And it seems that when your types in the same namespace then either only types from first assembly are registered:

```
container.Register(Types.FromAssemblyNamed("v1.com.foo").BasedOn(typeof(IRepository<>)).WithService.Base());
container.Register(Types.FromAssemblyNamed("v2.com.foo").BasedOn(typeof(IRepository<>)).WithService.Base());
```

or exception *'There is already a component with that name. Did you want to modify the existing component instead? If not, make sure you specify a unique name.'* is thrown:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IRepository<v1Alias::com.foo.Data>>().ImplementedBy<v1Alias::com.foo.Repository>());
container.Register(Component.For<IRepository<v2Alias::com.foo.Data>>().ImplementedBy<v2Alias::com.foo.Repository>());
```

If you **put different versions of your types into different namespaces** (e.g. `com.foo.v1`, `com.foo.v2`) all your types will be registered.

There'll be no difference how you register them:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IRepository<v1.com.foo.Data>>().ImplementedBy<v1.com.foo.Repository>());
container.Register(Component.For<IRepository<v2.com.foo.Data>>().ImplementedBy<v2.com.foo.Repository>());
```

or

```
container.Register(Types.FromAssemblyNamed("v1.com.foo").BasedOn(typeof(IRepository<>)).WithService.Base());
container.Register(Types.FromAssemblyNamed("v2.com.foo").BasedOn(typeof(IRepository<>)).WithService.Base());
```

PS: If this solution doesn't work for you then you can [post an issue on GitHub or create a pull request with your fix](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor).

Comment: Looking at the question closer, the question didn't apply to my actual circumstance, but I'll accept to make sure you get the bounty.  Min was a situation where assemblies are being loaded by directory, and somewhere in running unit tests something is getting registered more than once, probably due to concurrent threads in the test runner.

Comment: It should not register anything twice. During second registration it likely throws an exception.

Comment: Yes, the second registration exception is the problem, I wish it would just register twice since it's breaking my tests.

Comment: I forgot about the question.  I came to a solution by way of work around as well as having a fix in the source for which I was to lazy to bother with.  Just trust that there is a reason for the different namespace with same type.