# Reference a DLL but only import some of the classes in it

Tags: c#, wcf, dll

I am consuming a legacy WCF service and need to put a ParameterInspector implementation onto the ServiceContract.

I have written a new contract with the ParameterInspector implementation fine, but the problem with this is that the Legacy service implementation has both the contract interface AND the service implementation in the same DLL.

i.e. LegacyDll.dll contains these namespaces

```
Legacy.Namespace.IService
Legacy.NameSpace.Service (: IService)
```

I have written the following namespace

```
namespace Legacy.Namespace
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {

        [CustomDataOperationBehavior]
        [OperationContract]
        bool Methods(); ......
```

Everything works fine until I try to use the NEW contract (with the ParameterInspector) and the OLD service DLL, because the OLD service DLL serviceContract is the same namespace as the new ServiceContract.

So, my question is, can I reference `LegacyDll.dll` and somehow ignore the ServiceContract in it. i.e. partially reference a DLL ??

Comment: you refer to my nemesis :)

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672920/two-different-dll-with-same-namespace

Comment: Thanks, extern alias allowed me to import both and just the one I needed