# Project with 2 different DLLs that have the same name

Tags: c#

Project1(ASP.NET WebApp) has a reference to DAL.dll (DAL comes from Data Access Layer).
Project2(Class Library) also has a reference to a totally different DAL.dll.

I added Project2 as a reference to Project1, but when I run the program I get an error because Project2 uses the DAL.dll of Project1.

What to do?

Comment: Its a good idea to name your libraries with more unique names. e.g. WebApp.DataAccess.dll and MyLib.DataAccess.dll. Otherwise you are just asking for trouble.

Comment: similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672920/two-different-dll-with-same-namespace

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Option - Rename Project to Be Unique**

So, with this issue you have two options, the simplest way (and best way in my opinion ) is to always prefix your projects so they end up being unique.

Not Unique : `Data.Access.Layer`

Unique     : `CompanyName.ProjectName.Data.Access.Layer`