# Is it possible to use Path.GetRelativePath (.NET Core2) in WinForms proj targeting 4.7.1?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

This seems to be a pretty simple question, yet googling yield nothing useful.

I have VS2017 WinForms C# project targeting .NET Framework 4.7.1.

I would like to make use of [Path.GetRelativePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getrelativepath) from [.NET Core 2.X](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/Path.cs#L697).

Is it achievable (nuget package or something)?

PS. For those who are lazy to port .NET Core code themselves here is [my adapted version of it](https://gist.github.com/antonKrouglov/07ccc117cb8c30ad8994446a86c062e5).

Comment: Try import the `System.Runtime.Extensions.dll` from dotnetcore. If you have problems with classes with the same name, because .net framework already have a `System.IO` namespace, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3672987/5762332)

Comment: @Magnetron How do I _import the System.Runtime.Extensions.dll from dotnetcore_?

Comment: Yeah, it was just a thought because that's the assembly the article says it belongs to. I tried here but I couldn't do it. The nuget version gave me no classes, so I built a dotnet core app to pick the assembly, it gave me some classes but didn't gave me the Path class.

Answer (score 10):

A workaround: If for some reason, the Core library cannot be referenced or called at runtime, you can implement the function yourself, it is quite simple:

```
public string GetRelativePath(string relativeTo, string path)
{
    var uri = new Uri(relativeTo);
    var rel = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(path)).ToString()).Replace(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
    if (rel.Contains(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()) == false)
    {
        rel = $".{ Path.DirectorySeparatorChar }{ rel }";
    }
    return rel;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, yet another variant of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/how-to-get-relative-path-from-absolute-path