# Can two classes with the same name be in the same namespace across two different assemblies?

Tags: c#, namespaces, .net-assembly

I have two different assemblies: `Assembly1` and `Assembly2`. Both assemblies use the same namespace `SoftwareDrivers`. Now, I have two implementations of a class that has identical functionality, just different implementation and dependencies that tie one implementation to `Assembly1` and the other to `Assembly2`; I'll call this class `PackageWriter`.

It is possibly, and likely, some projects will need to reference both assemblies, so I anticipate there will be an issue with resolving which `PackageWriter` to use in that scenario. Is this the case? If so, is the only way to resolve this issue, without changing the structure of the project, to change the name of `PackageWriter`?c

Comment: Why not simply try it out? IMHO it smells if two classes have identical names (and even identical namespaces) but do different things.

Comment: [`extern alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias). There are features that help you deal with these problems, but usually it's a sign that you're not picking good enough names. I.e. what actually *distinguishes* a `PackageWriter` that uses assembly1 from one that uses assembly2, and why isn't that part of the name?

Comment: If they have *"identical functionality but different implementation"*, then why not just pick the one with the better implementation and use that in both places?

Comment: @RufusL - if one should in fact be named `XmlPackageWriter` and the other `ASN1PackageWriter`, then neither is necessarily better than the other, but as I said above, it points to a naming failure.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I guess I don't understand why you'd have two different methods in the same namespace that have **identical** functionality. Maybe it should be phrased *similar* functionality?

Comment: @RufusL I have had to do this before when I needed to use 2 different versions of an API.  It's not ideal, but it happens.  However, I've never found myself purposefully writing code this way as it appears is being done here.  This absolutely smells, and begs for the use of a Factory pattern instead of this swapping assemblies nonsense.

Comment: @RufusL - because many people here describe things as being "identical" until you dig down into it and what they mean is in fact "superficially similar" but doing completely different things. Unless the OP wishes to contradict me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they can.  If both assemblies are referenced, you will receive an error similar to this:

`error CS0433: The type 'Testing' exists in both 'MyApp.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'MyApp.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'`

Note, you should never purposefully put yourself in this situation.  However, if you for some reason find yourself in a situation where you have to handle this:

Every assembly has an "alias" in .NET and by default it is `global`.  This is usually invisible to the day to day programmer.  You can change the alias by clicking on the reference and changing the Alias in Properties.  You would then reference it by having `extern alias myalias` at the top of your file, and the actual class referenced like this `myalias::MyApp.Testing`

This is perhaps needed when running 2 versions of an API or similar, although I maintain to avoid this if at all possible.

For more detail, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672920/two-different-dll-with-same-namespace).

Answer (score 0):

If it's within the same namespace then NO unless you are declaring it as `partial` class

Comment: partial would only work inside a single assembly. It's a compile time feature.