# Load a Specific class from dll in C#

Tags: c#, dll, appdomain

I want to load only some classes from a given dll.
The problem is the following:

I have the following of dll files.

**Dll 1:**

Namespace:

- Class 1
- Class 2

**Dll 2:**

Namespace:

- Class 2
- Class 3

As shown in the example above, it is possible and likely to happen that I have 2 or even more dlls with the same classes in it. (Note that the namespaces are the same)

Now I thought of the following:

- Open a dll in a Temp AppDomain
- Check which classes we do not know
- Move needed classes to Standard Appdomain
- Unload Temp Appdomain

Is there any way to do something like that?

Comment: Are you asking about late binding?  I had a system I worked on that late binded a DLL (a master VB.net project that late binded a DLL from a project written in C#) which we then called a function by string name within that DLL to start the ball rolling (it was an automated telephone system).

Comment: Are the dlls under your control?

Comment: @Fildor Every dll is autogenerated from a Programm I have full control of

Comment: Try to use _extern alias_ This thread can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672920/two-different-dll-with-same-namespace

Comment: When do you know which version of any conflicting classes you will need (Namespace.Class2 in your example above)....not until run time?

Comment: @RichardII this is the exact Problem, I do not know, until run time

Comment: Will the conflicting classes (Class2 in your example) have the same public interface, i.e., same public (and "internal") method names and signatures, same public properties, etc?    If not, without a code sample, I have trouble grasping how you plan to use this.

Comment: Different DLLs using the same class names sounds close to using a plug-in mechanism. [Here is a tutorial how to](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-a-simple-plugin-b6174b62).

Answer (score 0):

You have two different dll file. So You can import two different dll file into you C# project.
For example first dll file's name is  "File1" and second dll file's name is "File2"

```
const string file1_Dll_Path = @"File1.dll";
const string file2_DllPath = @"File2.dll";
[DllImport(file2_DllPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int YOURFUNCTIONINFILE2DLL();
[DllImport(file1_Dll_Path, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void YOURFUNCTIONINFILE1DLL();
```

Note: Don't forget adding "unsafe" your C# Form. Like this

```
unsafe public partial class FORMNAME : Form
```

Comment: This would help if i knew wich classes I have to load on Build time.
But I know only at run time wich classes I need