# Using multiple dll-s with same namespace

Tags: c#, dll

I have two dll-s with the same name and both are version 1.0.0.0 but they are different.
One is newer and has some stuff implemented that older one doesn't.
I have to use both of them since they support different devices.
I used aliases and it worked for older dll. I could reference it by alias but I couldn't use newer one that was in global alias nor in new alias.

```
Error   CS0430  The extern alias 'New_Interop' was not specified in a /reference option *.Driver                                            C:\Users\*\source\repos\*\*.Driver\*.cs 1   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name '*' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) *.Driver    C:\Users\*\source\repos\*\*.Driver\*.cs 15  Active
```

Tryed this, didn't help:
[two different DLL with same namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672920/two-different-dll-with-same-namespace)

Comment: I would contact the suppliers of the DLLs and ask them to sort their mess out. Releasing two DLLs with the same version number but different contents is simply broken.

Comment: I will try reaching them but I don't have much hope they will answer at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made wrapper around old one and included it as OldInterop with that namespace.