# How to Use 2 libraries (contain a Shared Class) in a Project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, shared-libraries, shared-project

i have a Shared Project `(SharedProject1)` with a Class Called `myDataInfo.cs` and 2 Libraries `(Common.csproj and CustomControls.csproj)`

, this two libraries uses SharedProject1. now i am using this 2 libraries in a Project Called `Test.csproj`. now when i want to use myDataInfo.cs i get an error that say

> myDataInfo.cs is exist in both Common.csproj and CustomControls.csproj

Comment: See: [What is the difference between a Shared Project and a Class Library in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634753/what-is-the-difference-between-a-shared-project-and-a-class-library-in-visual-st)

Comment: I also tend to rely on dlls rather than source code so they are all in their own namespace. There will be no repetition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared projects share the source code, not the compiled code. This means that if two projects share the same code they will compile it twice. This results in having two distinct types `myDataInfo` in `Common` and a `myDataInfo` in `CustomControls`. They happen to have the same name but they are two distinct types. This is because types are identified by their [fully qualified type names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/specifying-fully-qualified-type-names) which consists of an assembly name specification, a namespace specification, and a type name.

Therefore you must share the assemblies (DLLs, EXEs, Packages or Project References), not the source code (Shared Projects).

```
        ┌────────────────────┐
        │ SharedProject1     │
        │                    │
        │ (should be         │
        │  SharedLibrary1)   │
        │                    │
        └────────────────────┘
          ▲       ▲       ▲
          │       :       │
          │       :       │
          │       :       │
  ┌───────┴──┐    :   ┌───┴─────────────┐
  │ Common   │    :   │  CustomControls │
  └──────────┘    :   └─────────────────┘
           ▲      :    ▲
           │      :    │
       ┌───┴──────┴────┴──┐
       │      Test        │
       └──────────────────┘
```

In `Test` the reference to `SharedProject1` is only required if `Test` accesses `myDataInfo` directly.

See also:

- [What is the difference between a Shared Project and a Class Library in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30634753/880990)
- [How to: Add or remove references by using the Reference Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2022)
- [Same Class in Same Namespace in Different Projects](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6ddd7d6b-fdd8-4a7c-b3eb-1f6d5284a67a/same-class-in-same-namespace-in-different-projects?forum=csharplanguage)
- [two different DLL with same namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3672920/880990)

Comment: So i should change sharedlibrary1 to a classlibrary project?

Comment: Yes, and compile it and then reference the resulting DLL in the other projects. Or if they are in the same Solution you can also make a project reference (the advantage is that both compile with the same configuration Debug or Release). Or you can reference it as a NuGet Package if it is one.

Comment: 1+ for ascii magic - what tool did you use for this? :D

Comment: [ASCIIFlow](https://asciiflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

Libraries should not use projects. Project depends on libraries. Seems as a structural problem of your application.
My suggestion of dependency tree:
Test.csproj -> SharedProject1.csproj ->(Common.csproj, CustomControls.csproj)

Comment: Test.csproj is a winui app, common and customcontrols is a nuget package. so i need to use a shared class. i dont want to add shared project in test.csproj (because user create this and only install nuget packages)